# Elements to make a rocket taking off sound

Tags: space, sound-design, showreel

I'm designing my showreel and have chosen a clip from the film Apollo 13 where the rocket takes off. I'm wondering what sort of sounds I could use. I was thinking something synth based for the low end but the mid-high is what I'm struggling with. (also falling ice is something I'm confused about)
I have a few samples of power tools (such as drills and a wood lathe) and some fireworks. I have to source everything from scratch.
Here's a link to the clip: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kgHYGw9OL7c#t=127s 
(my clip finishes at 2:22)
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a combination of blowing unevenly into a microphone for an extended period of time (also blowing with gravel in your voice) then layering it at different low pitches for the distorted rocket effect, the falling ice could be achieved by cracking a head of lettuce (great for flesh as well as a myriad of other splintering type sounds). Synth helps for low end too. As for the liftoff it should be a quick breath with heavy low end added. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> > watch these videos!!!!!!!!<<

http://soundworkscollection.com/halo-reach

http://soundworkscollection.com/flight

The halo one really breaks it down about 2 minutes in.